# Java classpath entry

Tags: java, path

I am trying to use [this project](https://github.com/wenerme/Lizzy).
When i am running from /home/chris/eclipse-workspace/KplPlaylist/src/Lizzy/test the file AddToPlaylist.sh with:

`./AddToPlaylist.sh -t kpl /home/chris/Μουσική/Αναστάσιμα τροπάρια`

I get the following mistakes:

`chris@chris-Inspiron-3847:~/eclipse-workspace/KplPlaylist/src/Lizzy/test$ ./AddToPlaylist.sh -t kpl /home/chris/Μουσική/Αναστάσιμα τροπάρια
Error: Could not find or load main class christophedelory.lizzy.AddToPlaylist
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: christophedelory.lizzy.AddToPlaylist`

The AddToPlaylist.sh file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
root=`dirname $0`
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$root/lib
java -cp "$root/lizzy.jar:$root/lib/args4j.jar:$root/classes" christophedelory.lizzy.AddToPlaylist $*
```

How can i add a classpath entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same directory (i.e. `~/eclipse-workspace/KplPlaylist/src/Lizzy/test`) you should put `lizzy.jar`, `lib/args4j.jar` and `classes` directory containing, among other classes, the `christophedelory/lizzy/AddToPlaylist.class` class with the main method. This way the necessary dependencies will be loaded from the classpath defined by the `-cp` argument.

You can take a look at the build contents of the application on the SourceForge to get the `*.jar`/`*.class` (and other types if such are needed) files or build them yourself.

P.S.: The space in `/home/chris/Μουσική/Αναστάσιμα τροπάρια` should probably be escaped as it might be treated as the delimiter for the next parameter value.

Comment: I don't test your solution, but i think that's all i needed. Anyway i found the playlist files wanted in samples directory. Thanks!!